# Vue string matching in handlebars {{myString !== "" ? myString : otherString}}

Tags: javascript, string, vue.js, comparator

`{{myString !== "" ? myString : otherString}}` is currently printing `myString` which is an empty string

What is wrong with my comparator? I also tried using single quotes

The reason I ask this seemingly basic question is because the Vue documentation on handlebars doesn't seem to cover this, aside from letting me know that general javascript is available, I thought this comparator was general javascript for strings

Comment: i tried your example by setting `myString:""` and `otherString:"test"` and i set `{{myString !== "" ? myString : otherString}}` in my template which prints *test*, i think you have an issue somewhere else

Comment: Does `myString.trim() !== ""` perhaps have an effect on the output? Can `myString` be null or undefined instead of `""`?

Comment: @JonathanLonowski  yes it can. The model says myString should be a string but the mongodb object may not have that key, currently

Comment: @JonathanLonowski the answer was just using `if(value)` so therefore `{{ myString ? ... : ... }}`

Answer (score 0, accepted):

`if(value)` was the answer here, to cover all the conditions I needed

so `{{ myString ? ... : ... }}`

Answer (score 0):

The ternary operator works fine on the template.
Check your `myString` data it might not be empty.

```
  <div>Empty: {{myString === "" ? 'test' : otherString}}<div>
  <div>Non Empty: {{myString !== "" ? 'test' : otherString}}<div>
```

See the example below.

```js
var app = new Vue({
  el: '#app',
  data() {
    return {
     myString: "",
     otherString: "blah"
    }
   },
})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/vue@2.5.17/dist/vue.js"></script>
<div id="app">
  <div>Empty: {{myString === "" ? 'test' : otherString}}<div>
  <div>Non Empty: {{myString !== "" ? 'test' : otherString}}<div>
  
</div>
```